# How many ways can $10$ of $22$ different books be distributed to $10$ of $17$ children in the class?

Tags: combinatorics

It has $22$ different books and a class of $17$ children.
You want to take out $10$ of the books and distribute them to $10$ (different) children in the class.
How many ways can it happen?

My solution was

Selection by repeating the unorder Children: $$\binom{17 + 10-1}{10} =\binom{26}{10}$$
Selection by repeating the unorder Books: $$\binom{22 + 10-1}{10} = \binom{31}{10}$$

By multiplication principle, we get:$$\binom{26}{10}\times\binom{31}{10}$$
But it was wrong?
What did i do wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{22}{10}$ ways to choose a set of books.

There are $\binom{17}{10}$ ways to choose a set of children.

Then we fix a book ordering and select a permutation of children to receive books (or fix a children ordering and permute the books). There are $10!$ ways to permute your choices.

Thus $\binom{22}{10}\binom{17}{10}10!$ is the number of ways to assign our books to children.

Comment: Is it ordered or unordered Lars??

Comment: I assumed that both the books and the children are distinguishable. Does that help?